# Paypal IPN sends invalid response after successful payment completion

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

First thing first,
Language: PHP
Framework: Code Igniter

This is the first time I'm implementing PayPal payment in my website so that users can pay from their PayPal accounts to the owner. Obviously.

Tutorial I followed for implementing PayPal payment is [here](http://www.codexworld.com/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-codeigniter/).
And for implementing IPN listener, I used [this](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php) code.
I wrote IPN listener in core php and it's a standalone file (no relation with codeigniter framework or website). A cron job makes this file run 24x7. I thought that's necessary but not quite sure. So IPN listener listens every time and whenever PayPal sends an IPN, it takes the data from POST and checks the verification. If it is verified, it write the POST data to database and log a file accordingly.

This whole things was already a mess and I think I made it worse.

My IPN listener is:

```
<?php
require_once 'Query.php';
define("DEBUG", 1);

define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");
$raw_post_data = str_replace('=utf-8', '=UTF-8', file_get_contents('php://input'));
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) 
{
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));


if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

        $user_id = $_POST['custom'];
        $product_id = $_POST["item_number"];
        $txn_id = $_POST["txn_id"];
        $payment_gross = $_POST["mc_gross"];
        $currency_code = $_POST["mc_currency"];
        $payer_email = $_POST["payer_email"];
        $payment_status = $_POST["payment_status"];     


       $qry2="INSERT INTO payments(user_id,product_id,txn_id,payment_gross,currency_code,payer_email,payment_status) VALUES(".$user_id.",".$product_id.",'".$txn_id."',".$payment_gross.",'".$currency_code."','".$payer_email."','".$payment_status."')"   ;
      setData($qry2);   



    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
?>
```

What I'm trying to say here is , if the condition `if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)` is true, then only database write operation occurs and then I write to a log file using this `error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);`

I checked my log file and try to do a search for `Verified IPN` but couldn't find anything. Here is my IPN log.

```
[2016-03-07 05:41 UTC] HTTP request of validation request:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 for IPN payload: cmd=_notify-validate
[2016-03-07 05:41 UTC] HTTP response of validation request: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 05:41:03 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=WKlHKpJ3laas07Yu1WCXQPNlPGNpVTmx79in33FVjVu-1QcqQ1BKO2BLcO-ltHCgRNg4BYmHLqdIeaKPMYLdWqa1qP3eqTtCdlN-erDGl_NuifHufy7yejBynYZJS7W8xkoFUHBVW5eQocb6f3uGTwoVGpYBHeWXRejcU1o37sflJyynvgzkWMzHuvsG7pS9t19ZcqfrldHnv8pYpTXlBa4UeWbyuEVWiyuTVhBDE_UlA1L7E-Ho8J-rui0BFKqOHVsalakqcz9xP1XbyfIjb2hLrtpDDFmkqNqTs2ibxlGO-EjNhcJG1boI06ISlT4Dg0ZfGPlthPobrKZ0aS59OCOTaGOYReArBWqdDZXWq0tDwI8uIJwMaFT9w0fproQ5167v1nWS6QIZYnXmeZCO40Ss93NQW2OTeLRaKx-1e92aGSL3uxSq_YdE5Dm; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Thu, 05-Mar-2026 05:41:03 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Wed, 07-Mar-2018 05:41:03 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.108.11.1457329263101875; path=/; expires=Wed, 28-Feb-46 05:41:03 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: sandbox.slc
Paypal-Debug-Id: d4da8be813fa0
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D1863638358; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

INVALID
[2016-03-07 05:41 UTC] Invalid IPN: cmd=_notify-validate
[2016-03-07 05:42 UTC] HTTP request of validation request:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 for IPN payload: cmd=_notify-validate
[2016-03-07 05:42 UTC] HTTP response of validation request: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 05:42:02 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=f8rnnKoWpS27ajK43K_vGgiHMCbyL0kxcaLbl_qXj8X0JLk-LbcHgcR3owKzLqj_MJu_uo7CX7WOoie45aYro6IcO7wJJlXCvHm90MzDnGfwXjHYddOtovs9ZRpPcmiQ2o7Rxw6UhyVsaQ3stNXCFJ2RXouWssYRY8YTDST6VyVJWdtPzSIe24BebKqH2B1jbPOt_VJ1xhLRb_fmVpR6CB4ScN9fhgNdkyueDqEfp3o-xbT-VzHbfuTdSR3p2vvKKAVFBOs7ooDFmIylSOkxNkrBhvR2UwkGcpOo9HOBYWpqkfn2TlLBW6W1PpKSGnzY5M8TxaA-a1HtkKVMQ6TN4vyc46B7Ekps0ZLO3vtt9arFvvscgRMxOPGcQvwsGYrGHQv4Vyv_m47hrRRojf-yBdmebyhugsUKYSBjUSPiFDi5Ozg2inODpq0o0vC; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Thu, 05-Mar-2026 05:42:03 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Wed, 07-Mar-2018 05:42:03 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.108.11.1457329322876295; path=/; expires=Wed, 28-Feb-46 05:42:02 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: sandbox.slc
Paypal-Debug-Id: ec94240d19c4
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D2853494102; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

INVALID
[2016-03-07 05:42 UTC] Invalid IPN: cmd=_notify-validate
[2016-03-07 05:43 UTC] HTTP request of validation request:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 for IPN payload: cmd=_notify-validate
[2016-03-07 05:43 UTC] HTTP response of validation request: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 05:43:02 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=qFIftmj81M9XVbnGK-_ZFd_plIa-_hITqhkt7tHsSgU2hJnYg1P7b2xqdRFTOWeXIJnXWMBBwbAOFwF1azF07vQ_StCVY9SfONsm83OIv3S8WCTk9ekaXS6owbCFW4qVLtyDKxaKfNkLU576_BYmAFXULVJ3pAkLeGFUkzNC9kjY5ouHRKu3bzO7eSHrRpgQHnBQdoI6NcTHh697bQfeGAfFYpMIXDbYHEiSpaKm22v0j7hS4A_nntlaxbwrrRoZtZmTuoJdQNKF3wS26pJJkM4zYWpdY8xP21vISCk9sAAQjIOZCspps1tTjsXhDI4nYUZeJNjqG8xshBqB_lFweeqCQQC17MEivchn19F32ojFh--lfsp3cZA9YY34RBjxL1TnY-owkzw9n3qHpn-tnVP6--DgtJ-H3AqF0Q6QS3gCFam3tlNd5TEi9z0; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Thu, 05-Mar-2026 05:43:03 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Wed, 07-Mar-2018 05:43:03 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.108.11.1457329382840458; path=/; expires=Wed, 28-Feb-46 05:43:02 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: sandbox.slc
Paypal-Debug-Id: 8ad4234c9398
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D3860127062; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

INVALID
[2016-03-07 05:43 UTC] Invalid IPN: cmd=_notify-validate
```

There's nothing like '`Verified`' in it and log file has '`INVALID`' in it that means

```
error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
```

this function gets executed. **BUT DATA IS WRITTEN INTO DATABASE ALSO.**

I don't what's wrong here. Can anyone point out the mistakes? Should I take any additional security measures? Thanks. Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function success()
            {
                if(isset($_GET['tx']))
                {
                    $tx = $_GET['tx'];
                    $result=$this->verifyWithPayPal($tx);

                   // $this->load->view('success',$result);
                }
            } 
public function verifyWithPayPal($tx)
            {
               // $tx = $_REQUEST['tx'];     
                $token = $this->config->item('authtokan');   
                $paypal_url = $this->config->item('posturl').'?cmd=_notify-synch&tx='. $tx.'&at='.$token;

                $curl= curl_init($paypal_url);
                $data=array(
                           "cmd"=>"_notify-synch",
                           "tx"=>$tx,
                           "at"=>$token
                       );
                $data_string=json_encode($data);
                curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);
                curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                $headers= array(
                    'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com',
                    'Connection: close'
                );
                curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
                curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                $response= curl_exec($curl);

                $lines= explode("\n", $response);

                $keyarray = array();
                if(strcmp($lines[0],"SUCCESS")==0){
                    for($i=1;$i<count($lines)-1; $i++){
                        list($key,$val)=explode("=",$lines[$i]);
                        $keyarray[urldecode($key)]=urldecode($val);
                    }

                    $this->getListProducts($keyarray); 
                }  

            }      

public function getListProducts($result)
            {
             $i=1;
            $data = array();

        //        echo "<pre>";
        //        print_r($result);
        //        echo "</pre>";

                foreach($result as $key => $value)
                {
                    if(0===strpos($key,'item_number')){
                        $product = array(
                            'first_name'           => $result['first_name'],
                            'last_name'            => $result['last_name'],
                            'receiver_email'       => $result['receiver_email'],
                            'txn_type'             => $result['txn_type'], 
                            'txn_id'               => $result['txn_id'],
                            'payment_date'         => $result['payment_date'],
                            'payer_id'             => $result['payer_id'],                   
                            'payer_email'          => $result['payer_email'],
                            'address_street'       => $result['address_street'],
                            'address_zip'          => $result['address_zip'],
                            'address_status'       => $result['address_status'],
                            'address_country_code' => $result['address_country_code'],
                            'address_name'         => $result['address_name'],
                            'address_country'      => $result['address_country'],
                            'address_city'         => $result['address_city'],
                            'address_state'        => $result['address_state'],  
                            'receiver_id'          => $result['receiver_id'],
                            'receiver_email'       => $result['receiver_email'],
                            'item_number'          => $result['item_number1'],
                            'item_name'            => $result['item_name1'],
                            'quantity'             => $result['quantity1'],
                            'mc_currency'          => $result['mc_currency'],
                            'mc_fee'               => $result['mc_fee'],
                            'mc_gross'             => $result['mc_gross_1'],
                            'payment_gross'        => $result['payment_gross']                
                        );

                $this->load->model('mdl_order');
                $this->mdl_order->insert_record($product);  
             //   echo "alert<script>successfully Transaction</script>";
                if(isset($product)){
                        //echo 'hello';                       
                        $time=$this->session->userdata('last_time');
                       // echo $time;
                        //$data=array( $time=$this->session->userdata('last_time'));
                        $this->load->model('mdl_order');
                        $this->mdl_order->update($time);
                        echo "success update";

                }
//                redirect('manage_order'); 
                $this->load->view('success',$product);
                }
            }      
            return $data;  
        }
```

Comment: Can you give some more details, on why this code you post works and how adresses then problem?

Comment: An answer without any explanation is definitely not an answer.